# Redraw on Resize with Paper.js

Tags: html5-canvas, paperjs

I'm working with PaperJS. When I resize the browser window, I ask the canvas to redraw. However, the graphics do not re-center, as I draw the graphics from `view.center`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Demo</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/paper-full.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/paperscript" canvas="paperjs-canvas">
var center = new Path.Circle(view.center, 450);
center.fillColor = '#000000';

function onResize(event) {
    // redraw canvas
    paper.view.draw();
}
</script>
<style>
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden; /* avoid Mac / Chrome overscroll */
}
#paperjs-canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #D0E7D1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="paperjs-canvas" class="off" data-paper-resize="true"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

I checked from Developer Console that the resize function is called every time I resize the browser, but the `paper.view.draw();` does not re-align the graphics.

What did I miss?

Running on Google Chrome 41, Mac OS X 10.10.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`View.center` is just a regular coordinate. There's nothing special about it that keeps an object positioned there locked at the "center" of the canvas.

If you want to keep the same `point` as `view.center` after resizing the canvas, you can use `view.scrollBy(point)` to transform the coordinate system. Just keep in mind that the point [0,0] may no longer correspond to the top-left of the canvas.

```
var center = new Path.Circle(view.center, 240);
center.fillColor = '#000000';
var lastPoint = view.center;

function onResize(event) {
    view.scrollBy(lastPoint.subtract(view.center));
    lastPoint = view.center;
}
```

[Here's a sketch on paper.js](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/dY/BDoIwEER/pakHICENMZ4wXuQHiB7FQ6lLaKhb0xaIEv7dFhLDxblN3s7s7kSRP4Hm9NqBEy1NqdCP4AduiAB0YMiJIIyk5K5lhTRCQTxIGNlKU7I/ZMmxwtWyRipVaKVDLNpliyKPQ5/i1pVaovNsU+FphU2PwkmNROMFrPxADIOnCZkqJF7LvBVGK3V+x78mZvvaGS7c9qYk3BNC/xfO/tPaAO9eAVua3+7zFw==)

Comment: works like charm; it repositioned according browser resize. how about resizing the graphics based on the canvas size? is it possible?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: If you have a follow-up question, it's better to make a new post instead of asking it in a comment. I'm pretty sure this question has been answered a few times though. Try searching "[paperjs] resize" and see if any of those help.

Comment: Alex Blackwood, can you help me with a similar PaperJS Resize question I created? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74804127/paperjs-does-not-resize-drawing-in-canvas-correctly I'm unable to get a proportionally resized drawing whenever the canvas is resized.