# PaperJS does not resize drawing in canvas correctly

Tags: paperjs

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vt63Lxf7/4/

I'm using PaperJS on a canvas with `resize` specified.

```
<canvas id="mycanvas" resize>
```

Also, the canvas is set in CSS to have width/height of 100%:

```
#mycanvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The drawing is circles that depend on the current width/height of the canvas. If you try resizing the JSFiddle render panel, both horizontally and vertically, the drawing is supposed to grow/shrink proportionally, **but that is not happening**. The only way to get a new proportional drawing is to refresh the browser on the new JSFiddle render panel.

I verified in Chrome's DevTools that as you drag the JSFiddle canvas, its Width/Height changes accordingly, so PaperJS isn't picking up the new canvas size.

Answer (score 0):

That is how it is supposed to work. If you want the circle to resize accordingly, just add a fixed canvas.width and canvas.height.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding data-paper-resize property.

```
<canvas height="100" width="100! data-paper-resize></canvas>
```